# Does Resource Server in Spring make call to Authorization Server (Spring) on every request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authorization-server

I am new to Spring Boot and I am developing a simple API with few endpoints. Now I am implementing an Authorization Server (Oauth2AuthorizationServer) and Resource server with my endpoints. I have noticed that when AuthServer issues once a JWT token with provided credentials (I am using credential flow), Resource Server is able to verify the JWT even when the AuthServer is stopped. How that magic happens? I was thinking in the beginning that AuthServer must authorize every request made to the resource server. I can't figure it out how Resource server is able to decode the JWT even the auth server is down. Please, can somebody explain it to me how exactly things work.

When I try to make the first request to Resource server and AuthServer is stopped, there is an error - that there is no @Bean with decoder().

Comment: A [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) includes the permissions (claims) and an issud-at time. It's signed and the resource server can check the signature to know that it can trust the token. It can decide based on the issued-at claim if the token is still valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security supports protecting endpoints by using two forms of OAuth 2.0 Bearer Tokens:

- JWT
- Opaque Tokens

---

The behavior you experienced means that you configured JWT Authentication, by specifying the Authorization Server with an issuer URI, for example:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://idp.example.com/issuer
```

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html):

> Resource Server will use this property to further self-configure, discover the authorization server’s public keys, and subsequently validate incoming JWTs.

It configures itself through the following steps:

> 1. Query the Provider Configuration or Authorization Server Metadata endpoint for the `jwks_url` property
> 2. Query the `jwks_url` endpoint for supported algorithms
> 3. Configure the validation strategy to query `jwks_url` for valid public keys of the algorithms found
> 4. Configure the validation strategy to validate each JWTs `iss` claim against `idp.example.com`.

An important note from the docs which answers one of your questions is:

> If the authorization server is down when Resource Server queries it
> (given appropriate timeouts), then startup will fail.

During the runtime, any request containing an `Authorization: Bearer` header is processed as follows:

> 1. Validate its signature against a public key obtained from the `jwks_url` endpoint during startup and matched against the JWT
> 2. Validate the JWT’s `exp` and `nbf` timestamps and the JWT’s `iss` claim, and
> 3. Map each scope to an authority with the prefix `SCOPE_`.

There is no communication between Resource Server and Authorization Server during this process, so it doesn't have to be up after startup.

---

The behavior you expected, in the beginning, is actually related to Opaque Token Authentication. Where Authorization Server is specified with different properties, according to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html):

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        opaque-token:
          introspection-uri: https://idp.example.com/introspect
          client-id: client
          client-secret: secret
```

> This startup process is quite a bit simpler than for JWTs since no
> endpoints need to be discovered and no additional validation rules get
> added.

At the runtime, it is also processing any request containing an `Authorization: Bearer` header:

> 1. Query the provided introspection endpoint using the provided credentials and the token
> 2. Inspect the response for an `{ 'active': true }` attribute
> 3. Map each scope to an authority with the prefix `SCOPE_`

This means that the token is valid only if the Authorization Server responds that it is.